# How to get value of the ObservableField in android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android, android-databinding

Hi I have this `ObservableField` in my java code. I want to get the value of it which can be done by calling `get` method on it.

```
val email = ObservableField<String>()
```

This can be done using below approach. I am confused and don't know should I make a getter here to get the value of it ? or there is different standard approach to get the value of `ObservableField` I am using RxJava too in my app.

```
fun login(view: View) {
    val emailVal = email.get()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is good enough to use `email.get()`. If you really want to eliminate the use of `.get()` in your code, you may use backing field:

```
val _email = ObservableField<String>()
var email: String
    get() = _email.get()
    set(value) = _email.set(value)

//use
fun login(view: View) {
    val emailVal = email
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what delegation is about. Delegation of a property in Kotlin means having a class that implements the operator function `getValue` and optionally `setValue`, which will be called when accessing or updating the property.

Your delegate could look like this:

```
class <T> ObservableDelegate
{
    val field = ObservableField<T>()
    operator fun getValue(self: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>) : T
        = field.get()
    operator fun setValue(self: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: T)
        = field.set(value)
}
```

You can then use the delegate like this:

```
val email : String by ObservableDelegate()

fun login(view: View) {
    val emailVal = email
}
```

Read more about delegation of properties here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html